# How do I make a Gatsby image as large as possible in a container without sacrificing aspect ratio?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

Essentially, I'd like to replicate `object-fit: contain` behaviour but using gatsby-plugin-image to get the benefits of the image processing and source selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, `StaticImage` and `GatsbyImage` has a bunch of [shared `props`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#shared-props). In your case, `objectFit` is what you are looking for. By default, it takes `cover` as value but you can change it to `contain`. For example:

```
<StaticImage src="some/url.extension" objectFit="contain" />
```

Comment: this is amazing thank you! Such a nice simple answer.

Comment: Also, thank you for not telling me off for not posting code - I didn't think it was needed (not did the SO auto checks) and was proved right:)

Comment: Just did it, you answered so quick I had to wait 5 mins:)